# Inline-Block divs cannot both vertically align to the top

Tags: grid, vertical-alignment, css

Whilst trying to create a responsive 'grid' of two (div) panels (so that they are next to one another on wide screens and on top of one another when viewed on smaller screens), I noticed that the divs, when displayed 'block-inline', appear to align at the bottom. Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cY6GG/. Is there a way to reverse this and have both divs aligned at the top?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id='bigdiv'>
<h1>Lots of Content</h1>
<p>(lots of text)</p>
</div>
<div id='littlediv'>
<p>Not too much content</p>
```

And the css:

```
#bigdiv {
display:inline-block;
/*float:left;*/
width:40%;
background:#CCFFFF;
}
#littlediv {
background: #FFCCFF;
display:inline-block;
/*float:left;*/
width:40%;
}
```

I have tried:

```
float:left
```

But then it seems like there is no nice, semantic way to get the panels aligning horizintally in the center. All suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top;` to the styling for the #`littlediv`

Comment: This answered my question, I can't believe I missed it- Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

yes, add this to align them top `div{ vertical-align:top;}`

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can add `vertical-align:top;`to the divs to align them.

As for stacking them on top of each other on smallar screens, you need a CSS3 media query.

```
@media screen and (max-width : 600px)
{
    #bigdiv,
    #littlediv
    {
       width:100%;
       display:block; 
    }
}
```

Working fiddle: (drag the left edge of the output box to resize)

http://jsfiddle.net/FrF4y/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the vertical-align solved it. I am aware of how to use media queries, but thanks anyway!